# dplyr - How to obtain the order of one column within a group?

Tags: r, dplyr

**Example data:**

```
tibbly = tibble(age = c(10,30,50,10,30,50,10,30,50,10,30,50),
              grouping1 = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
              grouping2 = c("X", "X", "X","Y","Y","Y","X","X","X","Y","Y","Y"),
              value = c(1,2,3,4,4,6,2,5,3,6,3,2))
> tibbly
# A tibble: 12 x 4
     age grouping1 grouping2 value
   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>
 1    10 A         X             1
 2    30 A         X             2
 3    50 A         X             3
 4    10 A         Y             4
 5    30 A         Y             4
 6    50 A         Y             6
 7    10 B         X             2
 8    30 B         X             5
 9    50 B         X             3
10    10 B         Y             6
11    30 B         Y             3
12    50 B         Y             2
```

**Question:** 
How to obtain the order of rows for each group in a dataframe? I can use dplyr to arrange the data in the an appropriate form to visualize what I am interested in:

```
> tibbly %>% 
     group_by(grouping1, grouping2) %>%
     arrange(grouping1, grouping2, desc(value))
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   grouping1, grouping2 [4]
     age grouping1 grouping2 value
   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>
 1    50 A         X             3
 2    30 A         X             2
 3    10 A         X             1
 4    50 A         Y             6
 5    10 A         Y             4
 6    30 A         Y             4
 7    30 B         X             5
 8    50 B         X             3
 9    10 B         X             2
10    10 B         Y             6
11    30 B         Y             3
12    50 B         Y             2
```

In the end I am interested in the order of the age column, for each group based on the value column. Is there a elegant way to do this with dplyr? Something like `summarise()` based on the order of rows and not actual values

Comment: How do you want your final output to be? When you obtain that order, what do you do with it?

Comment: Are you looking for `row_number`?  As in `tibbly %>% 
  group_by(grouping1, grouping2) %>%
  arrange(grouping1, grouping2, desc(value)) %>% 
  mutate(RowNum=row_number())`

Comment: ....or something like this? `tibbly %>% 
  group_by(grouping1, grouping2) %>% 
  arrange(grouping1, grouping2, desc(value)) %>% 
  summarise(order = paste0(age, collapse = ",")) %>%
  ungroup()`

Comment: @AntoniosK That is pretty much what I was looking for! The order of the age column within each group. I wasn't aware of the usage of paste with collapse in that context. Very neat. Thank you!

Comment: @AntoniosK please post your comment as an answer so that the question does no longer appear as unanswered.

Comment: @Mojoesque Note that `arrange(grouping1, grouping2, desc(value))` can be used for visualisation purposes, but `arrange(desc(value))` after grouping is enough to do the job you want.

Comment: @AntoniosK is that just because the groupings aren't translated into ordering when printing the tibble? Are the two commands internally the same when used on the grouped tibble?

Comment: It because `arrange` ignores the grouping, but it doesn't cancel it. Therefore, within `summarize` the top value of a specific group will go first, then the second, etc. Or, in other words, the universal order doesn't break the within group order.

Comment: Right, the `arrange` - `grouping` interaction has confused me before , thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

tibbly = tibble(age = c(10,30,50,10,30,50,10,30,50,10,30,50),
                grouping1 = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
                grouping2 = c("X", "X", "X","Y","Y","Y","X","X","X","Y","Y","Y"),
                value = c(1,2,3,4,4,6,2,5,3,6,3,2))


tibbly %>% 
  group_by(grouping1, grouping2) %>%                  # for each group
  arrange(desc(value)) %>%                            # arrange value descending
  summarise(order = paste0(age, collapse = ",")) %>%  # get the order of age as a strings
  ungroup()                                           # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   grouping1 grouping2 order   
#   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   
# 1 A         X         50,30,10
# 2 A         Y         50,10,30
# 3 B         X         30,50,10
# 4 B         Y         10,30,50
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tibbly)[order(-value), .(order = toString(age)),.(grouping1, grouping2)]
```